# __init__ .. get_form_kwargs(self) which function called the other

Tags: python, django

I'm little confused about which of the following functions called the other one

is

> ___init____(self,*args,**kwargs) called get_forms_kwargs(self)

or

> get_forms_kwargs(self) called ___init____()

as I made the following mixin:

```
 class RequestformattachMixin(object):
          def get_form_kwargs(self):    
              kwargs=super().get_form_kwargs()
              kwargs['request']=self.request
              print(kwargs)
              return kwargs
```

and removed the get_forms_kwargs(self) from the  CBV in view.py and instead updated the CBV to let it inherit from the mixin

```
class LoginView(NextUrlMixin,RequestformattachMixin,FormView):
       form_class = login_page
       template_name = 'login.html'
       success_url = '/'
```

and didn't call the get_forms_kwargs(self) in CBV and it's working with no errors.

please need an explanation for that.

Comment: Neither. What makes  you think `__init__` and `get_form_kwargs` call each other directly?

Comment: So the how arguments passed from the views.py to forms.py done

Comment: Try changing the order to `FormView, RequestformattachMixin`

Comment: there is no issue with my orders, my question is how get_forms_kwargs(self) is called when I put it in the RequestformattachMixin(object) class, as I didn't call that function in the LoginView class

Comment: Are you sure the number of "_" characters in `___init____()` is appropriate? I think it should be `__init__()`

Comment: I really don't understand your question. In FormView, the `get_form_kwargs` method is called by `get_form` which is in turn called by `get_context_data` and `post`. You can see this [here](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/). I don't know what any of this has to do with `__init__`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman again , my question in brief to pass request from views.py to forms.py we have to override 2 equations which are get_forms_kwargs and __init__ , i have override get_forms_kwargs and the request is passed successfully to __init__ in forms.py.
then i modified and converted get_forms_kwargs() to MIixin as i will use it in multiple functions.

Comment: @DanielRoseman My question is: i put the RequestformattachMixin which has the get_forms_kwargs() as parent class.class LoginView(NextUrlMixin,RequestformattachMixin,FormView):
and removed get_forms_kwargs() form LoginView class.so how the get_forms_kwargs() is invoked even i didn't call it, is there any other function called it implicitly.

Comment: Well, didn't I just explain that?